# Regex Replace where previous character in match is not

Tags: .net, regex

For example there is a string  like

```
string x = "var test1 = $('#test1').val();"
```

I would like to replace only `test1` and not `#test1`.

C# code:

```
Regex.Replace(x, "[^#]" + @"\btest1\b", "test2");

*\b \b = match complete word only
```

when I use the `[^#]` doesnt replace the `#test1` as I like, but  the
`var test1` become:

```
vartest1
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to replace `#test1` as well? What about `not-test1-test2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Regex.Replace(x, @"(?<!#)\btest1\b", "test2");
```

[RegExr Example](http://regexr.com?37b95)

You've got the right idea but the reason your regex gets rid of the space between `var` and `test` is because `[^#]` matches that space.

`(?<=#)` is a positive lookbehind, it says look behind my match for `#` but don't include it in the match.

In this case you can use `(?<!#)` which is a negative lookbehind - look for something that doesn't match `#` and don't include it in the match.

Comment: No problem, added some explanation.